# In pdf.js unable to get pdfdocument.annotationStorage to update, and not saving

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Based on the examples, and using version 3.3.122 of the library, I am trying to fill out a form, and save the results.

I can see on the viewer.html, that when you update the field, pdfdocument.annotationStorage is updated, but when I attempt it, I can fill out the fields, but the values are not reflected in the annotation storage, and when I save, the values are not coming through.

Yes, I want to use pdf.js library!

`        var url = '/test/fw4_2.pdf';

```
    "use strict";

    if (!pdfjsLib.getDocument || !pdfjsViewer.PDFPageView) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
        alert("Please build the pdfjs-dist library using\n  `gulp dist-install`");
    }

    // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.3.122/pdf.worker.min.js';


    // Some PDFs need external cmaps.
    //
    // const CMAP_URL = "../../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/cmaps/";
    const CMAP_PACKED = true;

    const DEFAULT_URL = url;
    const PAGE_TO_VIEW = 1;
    const SCALE = 1.0;

    const ENABLE_XFA = true;

    const container = document.getElementById("pageContainer");

    const eventBus = new pdfjsViewer.EventBus();

    // Loading document.
    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({
        url: DEFAULT_URL,
        // cMapUrl: CMAP_URL,
        cMapPacked: CMAP_PACKED,
        enableXfa: ENABLE_XFA,
    });
    var pdfDocument;
    var pdfPage;
    var pdfPageView;
    var r = (async function () {
         pdfDocument = await loadingTask.promise;
        
        // Document loaded, retrieving the page.
        pdfPage = await pdfDocument.getPage(PAGE_TO_VIEW);
        // Creating the page view with default parameters.
        pdfPageView = new pdfjsViewer.PDFPageView({
            container,
            id: PAGE_TO_VIEW,
            scale: SCALE,
            defaultViewport: pdfPage.getViewport({ scale: SCALE }),
            eventBus,
            // We can enable text/annotation/xfa/struct-layers, as needed.
            textLayerMode :2,
            annotationEditorMode  : pdfjsLib.AnnotationEditorType.TextAnnotation,
            xfaLayerFactory: pdfDocument.isPureXfa
                ? new pdfjsViewer.DefaultXfaLayerFactory()
                : null,
        });
        // Associate the actual page with the view, and draw it.
        pdfPageView.setPdfPage(pdfPage);
       pdfPageView.draw();
    })();`
```

I have tried different so many ways of trying to load the document, saveDocument, getData, and setting annotations directly, with no luck.

I also changed the library versions, and I feel there could be some inconsistencies with the library.

Comment: Did you try `PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument._transport.annotationStorage.getAll()` and `PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument._transport.annotationStorage.setAll(jsonString);`?